# Find duplicate nodes neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I want to find all duplicate nodes per type in a neo4j database

Example : i have node1 with properties : name,adress,phone
i wan't to match all nodes that are duplicated without specifying the properties names in the query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this as well:

```
Match (n1:Person)
Match (n2:Person) Where id(n1) <> id(n2) and properties(n1)=properties(n2)
RETURN n1, n2
```

To ignore certain properties, try something like this:

```
WITH ['author', 'location', 'traceId'] AS ignoredProperties
Match (n1:Person)
Match (n2:Person) Where id(n1) <> id(n2) and ALL(x IN keys(properties(n1)) WHERE x IN ignoredProperties OR n1[x] = n2[x])
RETURN n1, n2
```

Comment: Pretty nice solution , have you an advice to exclude some params from properties ? like dates for example please

Comment: It can be done, in various ways, but the query won't be as clean as it is now. What is the exact datatype we are looking at `date` or `datetime`?

Comment: I have for example this properties : author , location and traceId that i wanna exclude

Answer (score 1):

Check first if all properties are the same then check if all values are the same.

```
//check that all keys in n1 and n2 are the same
Match (n1:Person)
Match (n2:Person) Where n1 < n2 and keys(n1)=keys(n2) 
//check that all properties are the same in n1 and n2 
WITH n1, n2, [ k1 in keys(n1) | n1[k1] ] as n1_props, [ k2 in keys(n2) | n2[k2] ] as n2_props
Where n1_props = n2_props
RETURN n1, n2
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe just group by and count:

```
match (p:Person)
with p.name as name,
p.adress as address,
p.phone as phone, 
count(*) as cnt
where cnt > 1
match (p:Person{name: name,  address: address, phone:phone})
return p
```

Comment: Sorry but i said without specifying the properties